# Github: Search code inside current repo

Tags: github

I know it is possible to search code inside a repo, by typing in the search box:

```
my-keyword repo:user_name/repository_name
```

But since I'm using a lot of projects everyday, and love to go deep inside the source code to see how this or that works, it very quickly becomes annoying to have to enter `repo: user_name/repository_name` part each time I want to search something.

Is there any way to search code quickly inside the **current** viewed repo source code?

If I'm currently on the `frankenstein/monster` repo, I want to be able to search for the `create_life` method without having to enter `repo: frankenstein/monster` in the search box, since I'm already in this repo.

(It's as if you are working on a file in your text editor, press Ctrl+F and need to enter the filename of the current file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update May 2013: see "**[Repository Search on all Repositories](https://github.com/blog/1492-repository-search-on-all-repositories)**"

> Today we are allowing you to search your own public repositories and any private repositories you have access to.
>
> When you're on a repository page, **you'll see an indication that you're searching that repository by default**:

[image]

---

Original answer (February 2013)

I didn't find any "`repo:current`" or other convention that would specify the *default* repo for a "Code" search.

I usually do my search in a separate windows, with "Code" selected and the "`repo:username/reponame`" already filled in.
I only add the keyword I need and click enter.

I repeat the process multiple time, changing only the keyword, but if a result is of interest, I open it in another tab, in order to preserve the search page and their fields.

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that in private repositories a second search bar labeled "Search source code…" appears. In this case simply hitting `Tab` twice will bring you there and let you search inside.

This seems not to appear on public repositories I sampled.

Comment: If this is present in private repos, I suppose it's intentionnaly removed from public repos. Maybe to avoid too many search. Too bad :( I'll investigate on private repo to see that. I think this distinction answers correclty my question. Thanks.

Comment: +1. I don't have access to private repos, as my answer reflects.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just wrote a very simple script that add automatically the current repo to the search box (works with TemperMonkey, and should work with GreaseMonkey) :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Github Current Repo Search
// @namespace  http://www.byscripts.info/
// @version    0.1
// @description  Add automatically the current repo in the search box
// @match      https://github.com/*
// @exclude    https://github.com/search*
// @copyright  2012+, ByScripts
// ==/UserScript==

var repo = window.location.pathname.substring(1).split('/').slice(0, 2).join('/');
if(repo.length) {
  document.getElementById('command-bar').value = "repo:" + repo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [brand new search provided by github](https://github.com/search).

For advanced needs, like searching a specific repo or user etc., use [advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced).

[image]

[image]